# obfuscating JPA entities with proguard

Tags: jpa, proguard

after obfuscation  i get the following exception :

```
org.hibernate.AnnotationException: No identifier specified for entity: com.ad.ac.c.a
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.determineDefaultAccessType(InheritanceState.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.InheritanceState.getElementsToProcess(InheritanceState.java:223)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindClass(AnnotationBinder.java:686)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processAnnotatedClassesQueue(Configuration.java:3977)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MetadataSourceQueue.processMetadata(Configuration.java:3931)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1368)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildMappings(Configuration.java:1345)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildMappings(Ejb3Configuration.java:1477)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.EventListenerConfigurator.configure(EventListenerConfigurator.java:193)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:1096)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:278)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:362)
```

i think it's do to the fact that Proguard obfuscates the getters and setters of the entities and changes the attributes names .

Answer (score 8):

Here is my proguard configuration required for JPA to work properly

```
-keepattributes RuntimeVisibleAnnotations
-keep @javax.persistence.* class * {
   *;
}
```

It will keep unobfuscated all persistence annotated classes, and won't remove any runtime annotations.